# How to get QLabel border size?

Tags: qt, size, border, qlabel

I have a label which has a border, it was set by this function:

```
this->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black");
```

But when I wanted to change the label's position, I had to also provide the width and height of the border, and I don't know where to get them from.

Comment: how are you moving its position? and a border only has a width (to be accessed and modified), its **_length_** is the length of the object (label in your case), and why do you need to provide these information? and to what do you need to provide it to?

Comment: The default border width is 0, and if you change it then you don't need to figure it out, so your border size is: `border_width=0` if you haven't changed it, and your border length (i don't think it's called height): `border_length=ui->label->width()`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the parameters might be obtained via `this->style();` that returns a pointer to `QStyleSheetStyle`... then via `renderRule()` one could get `QRenderRule` that stores all the structures required. The only problem is that those methods are **private** and intended for internal use.

So the simplest way is to use RegExp:

```
QRegExp regexp(".*border: *(\\d+)px.*");
if (regexp.indexIn(btn->styleSheet()) >= 0)
    qDebug() << regexp.cap(1);
```

Comment: Just to add more clarification, this will only work if a custom stylesheet is set, it will work for the OP, but for future reference, this should be mentioned. And it only provides the border width.